# Corona virus and food transmission

Tags: covid-19, disease-transmission, disease

I find conflicting info on [this](https://www.cdc.gov/foodsafety/newsletter/food-safety-and-Coronavirus.html) CDC cite it says

> Currently there is no evidence to support transmission of COVID-19
> associated with food

next it says

> It may be possible that a person can get COVID-19 by touching a
> *surface* or object that has the virus on it and then touching their own
> mouth,

So can't the food I eat act as a *surface* which has covid on it because someone sneezed on it?

PS even [this](https://medical.mit.edu/covid-19-updates/2020/06/how-should-i-clean-fruits-and-veggies) says you can't get it from foods based on that CDC article, but what about the conflicting info I am referring to?

Comment: Sure it can, it's that it's hard to prove such cases happen as you describe, since in such circumstance they'll also breathe in your face or at least in proximity... There's been a lot of expert debate on whether aerosols or the larger spit/sneeze particles are the main factor... insofar somewhat inconclusive https://www.medpagetoday.com/special-reports/exclusives/92564

Answer (score 1):

There is no conflict.

> Currently there is no evidence

means *there is no evidence*. It doesn't mean there is evidence *against*, it means that there is no evidence. They don't know of a person who has caught COVID-19 through food that was not exposed in some other way. The lack of evidence is suggestive that this isn't a major route of spread, though.

> It may be possible that a person can get COVID-19 by touching a surface or object

means *it may be possible*. Evidence for this possibility might include swabbing surfaces and finding you can culture the virus from those swabs. There are other viruses (particularly those causing gastrointestinal illness, [norovirus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norovirus) for example) that transmit often through a hand-to-mouth route. However, you're missing the end of the sentence in seeing a conflict:

> this is not thought to be the main way the virus spreads.

In summary, there is no evidence (no known cases of spread) COVID-19 transmits through food, and although there is a hypothetical possibility it isn't thought to be particularly important from an epidemiological standpoint.